# How to enable the recommended ESLint rules in eslint.config.js?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I’m trying to use the [new ESLint configuration file](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files-new) eslint.config.js (since the [old ESLint configuration files](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files) .eslintrc.* and package.json will be deprecated in ESLint 9.0.0). The [recommended ESLint rules](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules) were enabled by the `"extends": "eslint:recommended"` property in the old configuration files, but [that property does not exist anymore](https://eslint.org/blog/2022/08/new-config-system-part-2/#goodbye-extends%2C-hello-flat-cascade) in the new configuration file which relies on `import` statements.

So I tried this `import` in eslint.config.js:

```js
import config from 'eslint-config-standard';

export default [
  {
    rules: config.rules
  }
];
```

But I got this `TypeError`:

```bash
$ npm exec eslint .
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 8.39.0

TypeError: Key "rules": Key "import/export": Could not find plugin "import".
```

**How to solve that issue?**

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files-new#using-predefined-configurations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is described in the “[Using predefined configurations](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files-new#using-predefined-configurations)” section:

```js
import js from "@eslint/js";

export default [
    js.configs.recommended,
    {
        // your configuration here
    }
];
```